# Write protected pendrive

Tags: ubuntu

I have a pen drive with two partitions. But both partitions became read only. I tried to format. It did not happen. I even gparted to delete partition. This also did not work.

Why is my pen drive read-only, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: What kernel messages do you get when you plug in the drive? E.g., run `tail -F /var/log/kern.log` in a terminal, plug in the drive, and see which messages appear (some should). Please edit them in to your question.

Comment: @Jan presumably the question is "why is my drive read-only and how do I fix it?" USB sticks don't normally have a write-protect tab... I guess I'll edit the question to add it in.

Comment: @derobert, older ones did have a write-protect thingy.

Comment: @vonbrand Hmmm, wasn't aware of that. Curious, was it an actual hardware write-protect or just a flag honored by software if it felt like it?

Comment: @derobert, I believe it works at the drive level. But just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

Some (mostly older) pendrives have a write-protect switch (mostly invisible). Check for that.

Other possibilities are just a busted pendrive, or a dirty/broken connection. As the comments say, check kernel messages.

I'd just toss it, or keep it for it's curiosity value. They aren't *that* expensive anymore...